# Can Joomla 1.7 ACL control view permission of extensions for users?

Tags: joomla

I need to create view permissions of some extensions and some parts of other extensions for users.
Can Joomla 1.7 ACL control view permission of extensions for users?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you have set up a specific user group. For example:

- You can set permissions for specific groups for each of the module manager, plug in manager, template manager and language manager under the extensions menu as well as the extension manager itself,
- You can also set permissions for individual modules, plug-ins, so on and so forth.

from there what you could do is set up the following structure:

- Users who can see all of the extensions but cant change anything (example: user group a)
- Users who are a sub user that can modify modules only (user group a-i)
- Users who are a sub group of that but can only edit selected modules (user group a-i-1)
- Users who can also modify modules but cant modify modules that the users in group a-i-1 can (user group a-i-2)

and continue to drill down from there.